# I want to remove all occurrences of similar text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to remove all occurrences of  similar text starting with the word `MPRINT` followed by open parenthesis Having alphabets and numbers and close parenthesis and finally a colon.

I have 1000s of below mentioned instances in log files. I want to Remove All such occurrences.

Please guide me using regular expression in Notepad++

examples:

```
MPRINT(SCORINGRUN2011Q):
MPRINT(CHARACTERCLEANUPLONGFORM):
MPRINT(REMOVEUNWANTEDCHARACTERS2011):
MPRINT(CLEANDATA2011):
MPRINT(APPLYALLMISSPELL):
```

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: I suppose "Remove All" means replace the indicated occurrences with an empty string? Or the strings between parenthesis (string) have to be left in place?

Answer (score 0):

<s>It is not clear in your answer if you want to remove the entire line, or just the `MPRINT(text_here)` portion.</s>

Edit: OP wants to remove the literal `MPRINT()` as per comment below.

Using `regex` mode and searching for `MPRINT\((\w+)\)` will find what you've asked.
The "inner" set of brackets will capture the internal text.

Fill the `Replace with :` field with `$1` will replace the entry with the inner text when you hit `Replace`.

[image: Replace with Notepad++]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to remove only MPRINT(): portion of text on every occurrences.

Comment: @HarishPl I have modified the answer as mentioned.
Mark the answer as 'solved' if this helped you!